# Need help with proof concerning chaotic behaviours of the doubling function in discrete dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

The doubling function is given by

> $$D(x) = \begin{cases} {2x} &  x < \frac{1}{2} \\ 2x -1 & x \ge \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$$

We know that this function is chaotic on $[0,1)$ and

```
 A dynamical system F is chaotic if 
1. Periodic points for F are dense
2. F is transitive.
3. F depends sensitively on initial conditions
```

I can prove that condition 2 and 3 are true for the doubling function D(x). Can anyone help with the first condition?

Comment: Hint: how does $D$ affect the binary representation of $x$?

Comment: You can find a proof [here](https://marksmath.org/classes/Fall2017ChaosAndFractals/chaos_and_fractals/section-chaos_and_doubling.html).